# How to persist setting in document?

Tags: typescript, office-js, excel-addins

I'm developing Excel Add-in with the office-js. I want to flag documents that are using add-in's taskpane, so that when user will open this document next time, the task pane will open automaticaly.

I used the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document#tag-the-document-on-the-client-side) to solve my problem, but the `Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument` setting is not persisting in the document.
I've tried to log the setting by simple

```
console.log(Office.context.document.settings.get('Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument'));
```

right after settting it, and it returns `true`, but after saving/closing and opening the document again, when I log it, it returns `null`. I even unzipped the .xlsx file and searched for the `Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument` string, but couldn't find it.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in office-js?

Comment: Hi, which version/platform of office are you testing on?

Comment: @KeyurPatel-MSFT Office 365 on Windows, version 1906 (build 11727.20244)

Comment: Hi sorry for delay. so this is a bug in the April fork. Team is trying to get it deployed out, it is tracked here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/626